# What is the difference between these two codes it seems like they are exactly same but The second one causes a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I am trying to make different 1d arrays from 1d array each of which separated with space .I am using this in a project which is causing a serious problem to my code if i use the second one . Even debugging didn't help me.
This generally aims at converting a statement with spaces into a different strings. The first code does the job for me but the second one is identical but causing segmentation fault .

For Example "This is C program" is input
The Output should be 
    "This"              -must be in a[0],
    "is"                -must be in a[1],
    "C"                 -must be in a[2],
    "program"           -must be in a[3].

Here is the first one

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void gets(char *);
main()
{
    char str[100];
    char **a;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,count=0,n;
    printf("Enter a String : ");
    gets(str);
    while(str[k])
        if(str[k++]==32)
            count++;
    count=count+1;
    printf("%d\n",count);
    a=calloc(count,sizeof(char *));
    n=count;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)    
    {
        k=0;
        a[i]=calloc(1,20);
        while((str[j]!=32)&&(str[j]!=0))
        {
            a[i][k]=str[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        j++;
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        printf("%s\n",a[j]);
}
```

Here is the second one

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void gets(char *);
main()
{
    char str[100];
    char **a;
    int i=0,j=0,k=0,count=0,n;
    printf("Enter a String : ");
    gets(str);
    while(str[k])
        if(str[k++]==32)
            count++;
    count=count+1;
    printf("%d\n",count);
    a=calloc(count,sizeof(char *));
    n=count;
    for(i=0;i<count;i++)    
        a[i]=calloc(1,20);
    while(count)
    {
        while((str[j]!=32)&&(str[j]!=0))
        {
            a[i][k]=str[j];
            j++;
            k++;
        }
        j++;
        i++;
        k=0;
        count--;
    }
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
    printf("%s\n",a[j]);
}
```

Comment: @this.lau_ Done in the edit plz do not down vote for those silly ones

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It sounds like you may need to learn how to use a debugger to step through your code. With a good debugger, you can execute your program line by line and see where it is deviating from what you expect. This is an essential tool if you are going to do any programming. Further reading: [How to debug small programs](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: They are different: https://text-compare.com/

Comment: Ì just gave it a try and entered simply `ABC`. The at line `printf("%d\n", count);` the value of count is 1. Then somewhat further here: `a[i][k] = str[j];` you try to access `a[1]` which has never been initialized. Anyway your program is overly complicated und unreadably.

Comment: Note: Likely wrong prototype for `void gets(char *);`.  Use of this function should be avoided anyways.

Comment: Hint: What is the value of `i` in `a[i][k]=str[j];` in the 2nd code?

Comment: @Paul R The debugger part is already done

Comment: @MichaelWalz Using calloc intialises the values to zeros !!!

Comment: @chux yes done I have to again assign 0 to i thats the fault over there !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

2nd loop lacks re-assignment of `i`.  Deduced by [OP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046270/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-codes-it-seems-like-they-are-exactly-sa?noredirect=1#comment67383128_40046270) after [hint](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40046270/what-is-the-difference-between-these-two-codes-it-seems-like-they-are-exactly-sa?noredirect=1#comment67370844_40046270)

```
for(i=0;i<count;i++)    
    a[i]=calloc(1,20);

// add
i = 0;

while(count)
{
    while((str[j]!=32)&&(str[j]!=0))
    {
        // i has a value of count without re-assignment.   
        // This is UB as a[i] is eventually access outside range of a[]
        a[i][k]=str[j];
        j++;
        k++;
    }
    ...
```

Perhaps other issues?